# window.location.replace vs scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running on Chrome with the following snippets:

```
<a name="example">&nbsp;</a>
```

The following code works correctly. It actually goes to #example as expected.

```
window.location.replace('#example');
```

But the following does **not** work. It always go to the top of the page -- not to the `#example`.

```
var target = $('a[name="example"]');
var offset = target.offset();
var top = offset.top;
console.log(top);
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:top}, 'slow');
```

The `top` returns value 500+ something.
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE:

After removing the following CSS

```
position: fixed;
```

The above jQuery code works!. But I need this page to be "position: fixed;".
How do I make the above jQuery code works with "position: fixed;"?

Comment: what about using window instead of "html, body"?

Comment: To what are you binding this action to? Some click event?

Comment: It works in Chrome. However running the code directly from the Chrome's console takes it to the top of the page. So, check by binding the event to click event of some element.

Comment: I bind it using jQuery .live('click'). The binding works because it calls the same/correct function. I debug the function either using window.location.replace or scrollTop.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that your document is tall enough in order to scroll up to that position.  [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pAYsU/) using your own code and some HTML I made up to match it seems to work fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

if it works, you can add the fixed positioning after the animation is done:

```
var el = $('html, body');
el.animate({scrollTop:top}, 'slow',function(){el.css('position','fixed');});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the above does not work. It messes up my page layout.